# Error when testing Windows Speech Recognition API (SAPI)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, speech-recognition, sapi, hresult

I am trying to test the following example: [Test of Speech Recognition using Windows SAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16603703/4564882)

The code compiles well But It crashes in execution.

The returned pointer to ISpRecognizer Object takes the values NULL as shown in the following code :

```
// This function exits when the word passed as parameter is said by the user
int start_listening(const std::string& word)
{
.....

HRESULT hr;

ISpRecognizer* recognizer;
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpSharedRecognizer,
    nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpRecognizer,
    reinterpret_cast<void**>(&recognizer)); <<<<<ERROR: recognizer =NULL


<<< hr = REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG<< MEAN "class not registered"

check_result(hr); 

ISpRecoContext* recoContext;
hr = recognizer->CreateRecoContext(&recoContext);<<<<CRASH: TRY TO ACCESS TO 
                                                 <<<<  A NULL  POINTER
...
...
...
```

I am using visual studio 2015 on windows 8.1 and targeting x64 platform.

Do you know why the pointer to ISPRecognizer is NULL and why I am getting HRESULT=REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking that you're not calling ::CoInitialize() beforehand, and not properly initializing your ISpReognizer. I've got a fully working example as an answer to another question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358823/sapi-identifying-more-than-2-properties).