# Russian language recognition in Microsoft Speech API

Tags: sapi, microsoft-speech-api

I would like to play a little bit with Microsoft Speech API. I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358823/sapi-identifying-more-than-2-properties) and it works! I have tried to adopt it to recognize Russian language. The grammar file look like this:

```
<GRAMMAR LANGID="419">
    <DEFINE>
        <ID NAME="TEST" VAL="1"/>
    </DEFINE>
    <RULE NAME="TEST" TOPLEVEL="ACTIVE">
        <L>
            <P>Привет</P>
            <P>Пока</P>
        </L>
    </RULE>
</GRAMMAR>
```

The code is taken from [the mentioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358823/sapi-identifying-more-than-2-properties). But I get an error: the line

```
HRESULT hr = cpRecoGram->LoadCmdFromFile(L"D:\\data\\test\\reco_ru.cfg", SPLO_STATIC);
```

returns **0x80045052** (-2147200942): `An attempt to load a CFG grammar with a LANGID different than other loaded grammars.`

Is it possible to set up a program and/or an environment to use grammar files for Russian?

Environment: Windows 10 Home, Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Is that hexadecimal or decimal error number? What was the associated message? What was the HRESULT value?

Comment: @Ben The HRESULT value is -2147200942. The associated message is got with _com_error: IDispatch error #20050,please, read carefully. I do not know what does it mean and which type of numbers is used.

Comment: SPERR_LANGID_MISMATCH
0x80045052
-2147200942 An attempt to load a CFG grammar with a LANGID different than other loaded grammars  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/jj127491(v%3dmsdn.10)

Comment: Probably you need to initialise a fresh engine with the Russian language.

Comment: @Ben, ok, and how should I do it?

Comment: You would need a Russian language speech recognizer.   Microsoft doesn't ship one, and as far as I know, no such recognition engine exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 does not ship a SAPI-compatible Russian recognizer as part of the OS.   (There are en-US, en-GB, fr-FR, de-DE, ja-JP, zh-CHS, and zh-CHT SAPI recognizers available.)

However, if you're willing to use the Server recognizers (AKA the MS Speech Platform 11), you can find Russian recognizers at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224.

You want the MSSpeech_SR_ru-RU_TELE.msi download.

The Server recognizers have a similar API, but don't support a number of features that the SAPI 5.4 recognizers support (namely, dictation).

Comment: Could you please provide a list of available languages?

Comment: @LexSergeev rewrote the answer to clarify the distinction between SAPI 5.4 and MS Speech Platform 11.

Comment: Ok, let it be the answer )

Answer (score 0):

```
For Russian

CComPtr<Speechlib_tlb::ISpRecoGrammar> cpRecoGrammar;
......
hr = cpRecoContext->CreateGrammar(1,&cpRecoGrammar);
hr = cpRecoGrammar->SetGrammarState(SPGS_DISABLED);
hr = cpRecoGrammar->ResetGrammar(0x0419);
HRESULT hr = cpRecoGram->LoadCmdFromFile(L"D:\\data\\test\\reco_ru.cfg", SPLO_STATIC);
hr = cpRecoGrammar->SetGrammarState(SPGS_ENABLED);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
**for MS Speech Platform 11**

#define WM_RECOEVENT    WM_USER+190
CComPtr<Speechlib_tlb::ISpRecoGrammar> cpRecoGrammar;
......
hr = cpRecoContext->CreateGrammar(1,&cpRecoGrammar);
hr = cpRecoGrammar-> 
SetGrammarState(Speechlib_tlb::SPGRAMMARSTATE::SPGS_DISABLED);
hr = cpRecoGrammar->ResetGrammar(0x0419);
hr = cpRecoGrammar-> LoadCmdFromFile(L"W:\\GrSR.cfg",
Speechlib_tlb::SPLOADOPTIONS::SPLO_STATIC);
hr = cpRecoGrammar-> 
SetGrammarState(Speechlib_tlb::SPGRAMMARSTATE::SPGS_ENABLED);
hr = cpRecoGrammar-> 
SetRuleState(NULL,NULL,Speechlib_tlb::SPRULESTATE::SPRS_ACTIVE);
hr = cpRecoContext->SetNotifyWindowMessage
((Speechlib_tlb::_RemotableHandle*)hWnd, WM_RECOEVENT, 0, 0)
.........
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).